# Order of abelian subgroup of the automorphism group of an abelian group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-groups

Suppose $A$ is a finite abelian group and $B\leq\operatorname{Aut}(A)$ is abelian. Is it possible for the order of $B$ to be strictly greater than the order of $A$? What if I additionally impose that the orders of $A,B$ are coprime?

As a special case, suppose $p$ is prime. Can $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf F_p)$ have an abelian subgroup of order greater than $p^n$ (not divisible by $p$)? In other words, can an abelian group $B$ of order greater than $p^n$ have an $n$-dimensional faithful representation over a field with $p$ elements?

Edit: I just realised that the reasoning below is a bit silly, as $\lvert B\rvert<p^{n^2}$ is trivial, since $\lvert \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf F_p)\rvert<p^{n^2}$...

<s>Below, I make some observations about this last case. Suppose $B$ is an abelian group admitting such a representation and $p$ does not divide the order of $B$.</s>

Given such a representation, we can extend it to a representation over the algebraic closure of the $p$-element field and then decompose it into $n$ one-dimensional irreps. The image of a one-dimensional representation will be isomorphic to a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of the field, and hence finite, generated by a root of unity.

This root of unity will be an eigenvalue of a matrix in the image of the original representation, and hence it is a root of a polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbf F_p$. From this it follows that it is a primitive $d$-th root of unity for $d$ satisfying $p^m\equiv 1\pmod d$ for some $m\leq n$. This implies that $d<p^n$, which gives a weak bound of $\lvert B\rvert< p^{n^2}$, but I suspect it's not hard to get something much stronger.

Comment: For the $GL_n(F_p)$ question, it's possible to have an abelian group $B$ of order $p^{n^2/4}$ if you dont have the requirement that orders are coprime. Just consider matrices which have 1's on the diagonal and 0's everywhere except in the top right quarter of the matrix.

Comment: If you impose the condition that orders are coprime, then you are asking about maximal semisimple abelian subgroups of $GL_n(F_p)$ -- which is really a question about tori I guess. The maximum order is then $p^n-1$.

Comment: @NickGill: Thanks, these remarks helped a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Nick Gill points out, one can certainly have $|B| > |A|$ if you do not assume coprimality. If you assume coprimality then yes $|B| < |A|$.

If $A_p$ is the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $A$ then $\DeclareMathOperator{Aut}{Aut}$$\Aut(A) \cong \prod_p \Aut(A_p)$ and $B$ is contained in the direct product of its projections to the factors $\Aut(A_p)$, so without loss of generality $A$ is a $p$-group and $B$ is a $p'$-subgroup of $\Aut(A)$.

The Frattini subgroup of $A$ is $pA$ and $A/pA \cong \mathbf{F}_p^n$ for some $n$ (we are writing $A$ additively). Therefore we have a natural homomorphism $\DeclareMathOperator{GL}{GL}$$\Aut(A) \to \GL_n(p)$. The kernel is a $p$-group! Indeed, if $\alpha$ is in the kernel then $\alpha = 1 + f$ for some homomorphism $f : A \to pA$. Suppose $p^k A = 0$, where $k \ge p$. Then, by the binomial theorem,
$$\alpha^{p^k} = \sum_{i = 0}^{p^k} \binom{p^k}{i} f^i = 1,$$
since $f^i = 0$ for $i \ge k$ and $p^k$ divides $\binom{p^k}{i}$ for $0 < i < k$.
Now since $B$ is a $p'$-group it follows that $B$ injects into $\GL_n(p)$, and its image there has order at most $p^n-1$, by the second comment of Nick Gill.

To explain this last part (in one way of a few), first suppose $V = \mathbf{F}_p^n$ is an irreducible $B$-module. Since the $1$-eigenspace of any element $b \in B$ is a $B$-submodule, this implies that $B$ acts freely on the nonzero elements of $V$, whence $|B| \le p^n-1$. In general, $V$ is completely reducible by Maschke's theorem, so we may write $V = V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_k$ for some irreducible $B$-modules $V_i$. By the irreducible case, the image of $B$ in $\Aut(V_i)$ has order at most $|V_i|-1$, so the result follows.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very nice! Two small issues: first, you seem to be implicitly saying that $f^i$ goes to $p^iA$. Is that obvious? Secondly, I think it is worth stressing that the $1$-eigenspace of $b\in B$ cannot be all of $V$, since we are assuming that the representation is faithful. Also, how do you use the fact that $k\geq p$?

Comment: @tomasz We have $f^i(A) \le f(p^{i-1} A) = p^{i-1} f(A) \le p^i A$ by induction. The assumption that $k \ge p$ is just used to ensure that $\binom{p^k}{i}$ is divisible by $p^k$ for $0 < i < k$.

Comment: Thanks, this is completely clear now.

Answer (score 3):

**Claim)** Suppose $A$ is a finite non-trivial Abelian group. Let $B$ be an Abelian subgroup of ${\rm{Aut}}(A)$. Then, $|B|\leq |A|-1$ if $|A|$ and $|B|$ are coprime.

**An elementary proof by induction that does not use representation theory**

**Alternative 1)** There is a proper, non-trivial subgroup $M$ of $A$ preserved by every automorphism $f\in B$. Then any element $f$ of $B$ induces an automorphism of $M$, thus a  homomorphism $B\rightarrow{\rm{Aut}}(M)$. The kernel is $\{f\in B\mid f\restriction_M={\rm{id}}\}$, hence an injection $B\big/\{f\in B\mid f\restriction_M={\rm{id}}\}\hookrightarrow {\rm{Aut}}(M)$. On the other hand, the homomorphism $B\rightarrow{\rm{Aut}}\left(\frac{A}{M}\right)$ (well defined since elements of $B$ preserve $M$) restricts to an injection on $\{f\in B\mid f\restriction_M={\rm{id}}\}$ due to $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$: Suppose $f\in B$ is an automorphism $A\rightarrow A$ which keeps every element of $M$ fixed, and induces identity on $\frac{A}{M}$. Pick generators $x_1+M,\dots,x_k+M$ of $\frac{A}{M}$.  As the map $\frac{A}{M}\rightarrow \frac{A}{M}$ induced by $f$ is identity, for any $1\leq i\leq k$, there exists $m_i\in M$ with $f(x_i)=x_i+m_i$. But then, given $f\restriction_M={\rm{id}}$, one has $f^{\circ n}(x_i)=x_i+nm_i$ for every $n\in\Bbb{Z}$. We conclude that the order of $f$, a divisor of $|B|$, should be a multiple of $\min\{n\in\Bbb{Z}\mid n>0,nm_i=0\,\,\forall 1\leq i\leq k\}$. But this last number is a divisor of $|A|$ (recall that $m_1,\dots,m_k$ were elements of the additive Abelian group $A$). Hence the order of automorphism $f$ must be one. Consequently, aside from the injection $B\big/\{f\in B\mid f\restriction_M={\rm{id}}\}\hookrightarrow {\rm{Aut}}(M)$, we also have
$\{f\in B\mid f\restriction_M={\rm{id}}\}\hookrightarrow{\rm{Aut}}\left(\frac{A}{M}\right)$. Applying the induction hypothesis twice to smaller groups $M$ and $\frac{A}{M}$:
$$
|B|=\left|B\big/\{f\in B\mid f\restriction_M={\rm{id}}\}\right|\cdot\left|\{f\in B\mid f\restriction_M={\rm{id}}\}\right|\leq (|M|-1)\cdot\left(\left|\frac{A}{M}\right|-1\right)<|A|-1.
$$

**Alternative 2)** No proper non-trivial subgroup of $A$ is preserved by $B$. In this case, one can use an argument similar to Sean Eberhard's: For each $f\in B\setminus\{{\rm{id}}\}$, the proper subgroup ${\rm{Fix}}(f)$ of $A$ is preserved by all elements of $B$ because $B$ is assumed to be Abelian. Therefore, ${\rm{Fix}}(f)$ must be trivial. That is, the action of $B$ on $A\setminus\{0\}$ is free. This implies $|B|\leq |A|-1$.

**Note)** The argument above shows that equality in $|B|\leq |A|-1$ is achieved iff $B\leq{\rm{Aut}}(A)$ acts freely and transitively on $A\setminus\{0\}$ (the inequality was strict in Alternative 1). In such a situation, all non-identity elements of $A$ must be of the same order. Thus $A$ must be an elementary Abelian group, that is of the form $\left(\frac{\Bbb{Z}}{p\Bbb{Z}}\right)^{\ell}$ for a prime $p$. One example would be to identify $\left(\frac{\Bbb{Z}}{p\Bbb{Z}}\right)^{\ell}$ with the additive group of the finite field $\Bbb{F}_{p^\ell}$, pick a generator of $\Bbb{F}_{p^\ell}^{\times}$ and consider its action on $A=\left(\Bbb{F}_{p^\ell},+\right)$ given by multiplication. This amounts to an Abelian subgroup of order $p^{\ell}-1$ of ${\rm{Aut}}(A)$. (I am not sure if these are the only examples.)

Comment: This is a nice argument, thanks!

Comment: As for your last question, there are no other examples, but I may offend you by using representation theory again. We know that $B$ acts reguarly on the nonzero points of $V = \mathbb F_p^\ell$, in particular irreducibly, so by Schur's lemma, $K = \mathrm{End}_B(V)$ is a finite division ring, hence a field, and $B \le K^\times$. Since $K^\times$ is abelian and transitive on $V \setminus \{0\}$, $|K^\times| = |V| - 1$. This implies that $B = K^\times$ and $V \cong K$.